# how do I compress matrix to avoid memory error?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, scipy

Following is the numpy array I have. I need to create a matrix containing zeors for an instance like `np.zeroes([1,1])`.

```
newEdges = 

array([['0', 'Firm'],
       ['1', 'Firm'],
       ['2', 'Firm'],
       ..., 
       ['binA', 'year2017_bin'],
       ['binA', 'year2017_bin'],
       ['binA', 'year2017_bin']],
      dtype='<U21')



newEdges.shape 

#(63673218, 2)

newEdges.size
#127346436
```

However, based on the size of my matrix (as you can see above, that is, `(63673218, 2)`), if I run syntax to generate the zeroes matrix I get a `Memory Error`.

He is full syntax:

```
print(newEdges)
unique_Bin = np.unique(newEdges[:,0])
n_unique_Bin = len(unique_Bin)
unique_Bin
n_unique_Bin
#3351248

Q = np.zeros([n_unique_Bin,n_unique_Bin])

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-581dfaca2eab> in <module>()
----> 1 Q = np.zeros([n_unique_Bin,n_unique_Bin])

MemoryError:
```

How do I resolve this error? Or, how would I safely convert this huge matrix to a sparse matrix for further calculation done below:

```
for n, employer_employee in enumerate(newEdges):
    #print(employer_employee)
    #copy the array for the original o be intact
    eee = np.copy(newEdges)

    #sustitue the current tuple with a empty one to avoid self comparing
    eee[n] = (None,None)
    #get the index for the current employee, the one on the y axis
    employee_index = np.where(employer_employee[0] != unique_Bin)

    #get the indexes where the the employees letter match
    eq_index = np.where(eee[:,1] == employer_employee[1])[0]
    eq_employee = eee[eq_index,0]
    #add at the final array Q by index
    for emp in eq_employee:
        #print(np.unique(emp))
        emp_index = np.where(unique_Bin == emp)
        #print(emp)

        Q[employee_index,emp_index]+= 1
#         print(Q)

print(Q)
```

I have 24GB left in the memory for this calculation.

Comment: How many non-zeros will there be in `Q`.  What do you intend to do with the array after it's filled in?

Answer (score 0):

Just to point this out you are trying to create an array which is 3,351,248 x 3,351,248 in size. This is 11,230,863,157,504 entries! 11.2 trillion entries! The fact that you tried to print this makes me think you hadn't realised how big it was. I don't think you will be able to do this without sparse matrices. First of all you should probably make sure you need to do this and see if there is some other way.

Otherwise you can create a sparse matrix using scipy

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
Q = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((n_unique_Bin,n_unique_Bin), dtype = np.int8)
```

Then go from there.

Comment: `csr` format isn't good for iterative assignment.  `lil` format is better.